# Can't use onclick() with a nested function?

Tags: javascript, function, nested, onclick, dom-events

I'm trying to replace an image in an element with an `onclick()` function but the `leaveCave()` function is already nested within the `enterCave()` function. If I put the nested function by itself I cannot change the `leaveCImg.src` that has already been declared in the parent function.

```
function enterCave() {
    sceneImg.src = 'insideCave.jpg';
    caveImg.src = '';
    enemySpawn()
    updateMessage1.innerHTML = 'Please kill the ' + enemy.name;
    var leaveCImg = document.createElement('img');
    leaveCImg.src = './images/leaveCave.png';
    var leaveC = document.getElementById('leaveCave');
    leaveC.appendChild(leaveCImg);

    function leaveCave() {
        if (isEnemy) {
            update2('The ' + enemy.name + ' wont let you leave!');
        } else {
            sceneImg.src = 'town.jpg';
            caveImg.src = 'cave.jpg';
            leaveCImg.src = '';
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This way, you just define the "problematic" `leaveCave` and never use it..

Comment: You should add the onclick function codes to your question. It seems very unclear. Be more specific

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think you can just turn the entire thing into a class and then have the functions be methods instead, and have all of the variables etc. in the constructor function or something like that and then you should be able to call or change these variables from the methods that you set for the function. So you could have a class called 'Cave' and then you could put the default values in the constructor function and then create the 'enterCave' function and the 'leaveCave' function which then just manipulate those values. Then I think you should also be able to use the onclick() function.
I hope that I made a little bit of sense while trying to explain this.
Good luck!